# set an image between two div in html

Tags: html, css

I have two div `A` and `B`.
Now I want to set an image for both div like below image.
[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar-slider">
   <div class="navbar"></div>
   <img src="image_src" alt="Test Image">
   <div class="slider"></div>
</div>
```

Can't understand what will be the `css` position.

Anybody help please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could try putting the image inside your navbar, position it absolutely using bottom:0; then translate it -50% on the y axis, but you need to attempt something otherwise this question is off topic for SO

Comment: @Pete....will you please give the css code in answer section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.navbar-slider {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.navbar {
  width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(25%, 0%);
    background-color: green;
}

img {
    width: 202px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(25%, 50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.slider {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(25%, 100%);
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-slider">
   <div class="navbar"></div>
   <img src="https://static3.depositphotos.com/1000992/133/i/450/depositphotos_1337508-stock-photo-a-free-flying-white-dove.jpg" alt="Test Image">
   <div class="slider"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad i helped you ))

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div></div>
<img src="image_src" alt="Test Image">
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
div{
    height: 200px;
}

img{
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use position absolute and translate it Y -50%, by this it will always vertical center half of its height

```css
.navbar {background: #ccc;height: 100px;}
.navbar-slider {position: relative;}
img{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.slider {background: #333;height: 100px;}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-slider">
   <div class="navbar">Upper</div>
   <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/12F8N.png" alt="Test Image">
   <div class="slider">Lower</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the cooperation....just need to add `z-index` in `img` css. That's why choose sergey kuznetsov's answer

Answer (score 0):

**Try this.**

```css
.navbar{height:100px;background-color:#d37245;}
 img{width:200px;position:relative;}
.img{ margin: 0; position: absolute; left: 50%;
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}
.slider{height:100px;background-color:#d34545;}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-slider">
   <div class="navbar"></div>
   <div class="img">
   <img src="https://dcassetcdn.com/design_img/1559024/551167/551167_7840631_1559024_911ff84c_image.png" alt="Test Image">
   </div>
   
   <div class="slider"></div>
</div>
```